# How to texture cube with png image in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: textures, opengl-es-2.0

How do you texture a cube with png image in OpenGL ES 2.0? And how do you use atlas for the texturing?

Comment: Which platform is this for?  Using textures is generic OpenGL ES, but loading PNG images can be platform-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the good old cube demo, [check this out](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/Tutorial).

The code is written in WebGL, but you can easily convert it.

However, if you have trouble converting it, then I suggest you start with the "Hello Triangle" demo first -- to get used to this.

There are two links.

1. [Tutorial on Hello Triangle](http://www.webreference.com/programming/opengl_es/)
2. [Source Code for Hello Triangle](http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FWindows%2FChapter_2%2FHello_Triangle) -- Look at Chapter 2

To do the PNG part, you have a few options depending on your platform (Android, Palm, iPhone)

To give you at least one answer, if you are coding in C++, then you can use libPNG and that also requires zlib.  There are many sites with the code to load a PNG into a Texture using C++. [For instance](http://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2010/11/07/loading-a-png-as-texture-in-opengl-using-libpng/).

Good luck!